Use same audio output for MacBook and iPad
I have the following scenario:

Macbook with headphones connected (either wired or wireless) and some audio I need to listen to analyze (e.g. to play a song in Youtube/Spotify)
iPad with piano keyboard from Garage Band to play some basic chords or melody to follow the song

It would be great if I can use a single physical audio output for both devices (i.e. listen Garage Band iPad output in my MacBook headphones) to avoid switching from one device to another and to quickly check if what I'm transcribing from the song is ok.
Is there any "simple" way to achieve this? Thanks in advance for your help.

This little mixer should provide the utility you seek: https://www.amazon.com/Diydeg-Independent-Control-Amplification-Interference/dp/B0BHZBZNQ1/  Just get some short stereo 3.5mm cables to hook them up.
